# How to upload multiple images or files in a single input field using Django forms?

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms, integration, django-widget

I'm working on a Django project and I need to implement a feature where users can upload multiple images or files through a single input field in a Django form

I attempted to implement the MultiFileInput widget from the django-multiupload package within my Django form. I expected the widget to allow users to upload multiple images or files through a single input field.

However, I faced challenges integrating this widget within my existing form structure. While the widget appeared on the page, I couldn't figure out how to handle the uploaded files and save them to the database. The documentation for the package lacked detailed examples for this specific use case.

n short, I tried using the MultiFileInput widget but struggled with its integration and file handling. Any guidance or code snippets to achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated